# More than 20 Activity Stream Entries of IBM Connections with the REST API

Tags: rest, connection, activity-streams

I don't know how to get more than 20 AS Entries with the IBM Connections Opensocial API.
I use this url: SERVERNAME/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all but there is one parameter ("itemsPerPage":20) which limits the given entires to 20.

Does anyone know how to get more than 20 entries with the Rest API?

P.S.: I dont want to change the AS in IBM Connections! I know I could edit the config to display more entries, but I want to do it with the REST API and without changing the config

Answer (score 1):

`page`and `pageSize`don't work with the ActivityStream API. use the `count` parameter to control the max-number of returned results

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called page and pageSize

try this call

```
SERVERNAME/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all?page=2&ps=20
```

or

```
SERVERNAME/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@all?page=2&pageSize=20
```

Answer (score 0):

try startIndex

like this

YOUR_SERVER/connections/opensocial/basic/rest/activitystreams/@me/@mentions/@all?format=json&**startIndex**=1

seems like startIndex serves as a "page" variable.